# jQuery select where attribute = value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select an input where the value equals a dynamic value

```
trimmed = jQuery.trim(a);
preSelectedCheckBox = $(this).find("input[value=" + trimmed + "]");
```

The element exists but I constantly get no value returned. ($(preSelectedCheckBox).length = 0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you just missing the enclosing single quotes?

```
trimmed = jQuery.trim(a);
preSelectedCheckBox = $(this).find("input[value='" + trimmed + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preSelectedCheckBox = $(this).find("input[value=" + trimmed + "]");
```

forget the '' around the value